# Proving the indefinite integral $ \int\frac{\sqrt{a+bu}}{u}du $

Tags: integration

How can I prove that the indefinite integral

$ \int\frac{\sqrt{a+bu}}{u}du $

is equal to

$ 2\sqrt{a+bu} +a \int\frac{1}{u\sqrt{a+bu}}du$

Comment: Take the derivative.  If you can show it's equivalent to the original integrand, then you have proved they are equivalent.

Comment: good point they are equal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\int\frac{\sqrt{a+bu}}{u}du=\int\frac{a+bu}{u\sqrt{a+bu}}du=\int\frac{b}{\sqrt{a+bu}}du+\int\frac{a}{u\sqrt{a+bu}}du=2\sqrt{a+bu}+\int\frac{a}{u\sqrt{a+bu}}du$